# Get height of element then add class/change css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I'm trying to get the height of every h2 in a div, then if that height is higher than 21px, apply a class to that h2 or change his css.

The reason for that is that I have my project titles overlapping the tags when they're longer than a single line :

http://www.elisagilis.be

so far I've tried this :

```
$('.post-details h2').each(function(){
     if($(this).height() > 21)
     {
         $(this).css({"margin-top": "315px", "line-height": "28px"});
     }
 });
```

AND this :

```
$('.post-details h2').each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 21)
    {
        $(this).addClass('margintop');
    }
});
```

None of them work.
I've tried without using each as well, didn't work because it would select all of my h2 and apply the css/class to all of them.
- if you have a better solution than the ones I'm considering they're welcome as well.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you inspected the HTML or added a console.log to verify whether or not the `each()` is running?

Comment: What height are you querying specifically? Unless you've styled your `h2` elements then they should all have the same height.

Comment: @Aweary : Well they don't, because the 2 lines titlew have higher height. I'm having the problem when you resize the window to a smaller size. Long titles become 2 lines titles. That's normal, they have less width to expand. Tablets, per exemple, will see the 2 lines titles overlapping the tags, which I don't want. So I'm trying to find a solution for that issue.
Am I being clear ?

Comment: @jwatts1980 : I don't have any errors in the console. Should I be looking for something specific ?

Comment: The "resize" comment was key.. working on a solution.

Comment: Seems to work here - open web inspector, console tab and enter this code -  `var el = $('.post-details h2');
el.each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    console.log($this.height());
    if($this.height() > 21) {
        $(this).addClass('margintop');
    }
});` it turns out that it applies your class to first item, which is just about what you ask it for

Comment: @elisa You may want to consider removing the `position: absolute;` from your `<p>` tags inside the the `.post-details` and let the elements flow naturally

Comment: Why not just add a specific CSS class to your title elements and use CSS breakpoints to make the text size responsive? Why are you using JavaScript for this anyways?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
<h2>some text</h2>
<h2>some text<br>some more</h2>

.border {border:1px solid blue;}

$('h2').each(function(){

    alert($(this).height()); 

    if($(this).height() > 30)
    {
        $(this).addClass('border');
    }
});
```

Just change it to your preferences.

https://jsfiddle.net/370mg7ak/1/

Comment: Well, isn't it what I did above (second portion of code) ? :( Aaah I don't get it. And why the alert ? Isn't that a popup ?

Comment: Hmm maybe I've miss understood you, I just put that code together to show you that the (.each) function was working and it would alert the height of your h2 tags. Obviously you would remove that once you have configured it. I don't understand why your code is not working. Is the problem when you re-size your page?

Comment: Well, I don't think so, basically I need my titles to be perfectly positionned whatever the device, and then, the window width. Right now, my titles are overlapping the tags on a certain width, which is not good looking and the fixes I've tried so far don't seem to work :/ I don't know why, I'm still a bit of a newbie in Js/Jquery

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AHv7v/9/)

HTML

```
<div class="cta">
    <span class="cta-title">one line</span>
</div>
<div class="cta">
    <span class="cta-title">one line</span>
</div>
<div class="cta">
    <span class="cta-title">this will take up two lines</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cta { width: 100px; float: left; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; }
.cta-title { width: 100%; color: white; background: black; display: inline-block; }
.two-line { background-color: red; }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function(){
  var $tArray = $('div.cta').children('span');
  $tArray.each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > 18) {
        $(this).addClass('two-line');
    }
  });
});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the values change dynamically as the window is resizing, try this:

```
$(window).on("resize", ".post-details h2", function(){
    if($(this).height() > 21)
    {
        $(this).addClass('margintop');
    }
});
```

This attaches to the `window`'s `onresize` event and filters the events based on the `".post-details h2"` selector. However, in this case you may also have to account for if the page size is made larger again, then you also need the initialize case.

```
//Initial setup
$(".post-details h2").each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 21)
        $(this).addClass('margintop');
});

//On window resize
$(window).on("resize", ".post-details h2", function(){
    if($(this).height() > 21)
        $(this).addClass('margintop');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('margintop');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably remove the `position:absolute;` from the `<p>` tag and let the elements flow naturally. This way you won't have to worry about maintaining any extra javascript.

To get the 20px padding you have at the bottom you could add this style:

```
.post-details > a, .post-details p { transform: translateY(-20px); }
```

Comment: A solution using just css would be even better of course! But, unless I'm missing something, that solution leaves me with a bigger space under 2 lines titles :/

Comment: @elisa I would change the `line-height` of your `<h2>`'s to a smaller value and see if that helps. `.post-details h2 {line-height: 15px; }` should do the job

Comment: You may also want to add a small margin or padding to the top of your `<p>` to create some space between the title and the tags if you need it

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code

```
$('.post-details h2').each(function(){
  if($(this).height() > 21)
  {
    $(this).css({"margin-top": "315px", "line-height": "28px"});
  }
});
```

with

```
$(function(){    
  $('.post-details h2').each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 21)
    {
      $(this).css({"margin-top": "315px", "line-height": "28px"});
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up grouping my elements in a single div that I positioned with css only.